# cron job on plesk

Tags: cron, cron-task

So far I have tried:

```
php -q /var/www/vhosts/mediaservises.me/site1/ems/admin/cron/cron.php
php -f /var/www/vhosts/mediaservises.me/site1/ems/admin/cron/cron.php
site1/ems/admin/cron/cron.php
```

But none of them are working on `plesk`

What is wrong in my cron job command?

I want to run cron.php every 5 minutes.

Comment: define what's *not working* mean?

Comment: What do you expect, what do you have, why do you think it's different?

Comment: corn is not working. means it didnt run every 5 mins.

Comment: How can you be sure it's not running every 5 minutes ? **What do you expect to happen** and **What's happening**?